# Probability of losing network on any given day

Tags: probability

A large company has a private computer network connecting 300
different sites. Each site is connected to the network independently with a switch that fails with
probability 1% on any given day.

What is the probability that exactly two of 300 sites lose their network connection
on any given day?

What formulas can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Does "binomial probability" mean anything to you?

Comment: yes. In that case N =300, what would be k?

Comment: Well, you want the probability that _exactly two_ of the sites are down. What do you think $k$ might be?

Comment: Well, which integers apart from 300 occur in the problem statement?

Comment: Ugh...sorry, I completely missed that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two models are possible:

**Binomial.** The number $X$ of failures on any one day is $Binom(n = 300, p=.01)$
You want $P(X = 2) = {300 \choose 2} 0.02^2 0.98^{300 - 2}.$
You should look in your text for the
general formula of a binomial PDF, you should learn how to evaluate ${300 \choose 2}$,
and you should use your calculator to evaluate $P(X = 2)$ correct
to four places. These are things that might be related to exam questions. 
Using R statistical software, I got:

```
 dbinom(2, 300, .01)
 ## 0.2244143
 choose(300, 2) * .01^2 * .99^298
 ## 0.2244143
```

**Poisson.** Also, the number $X$ of failures on any one day might be modeled
as $Pois(\lambda = 3)$, where 3 is the average number of failures
per day. Then $P(X = 2) \approx e^{-3}3^2/2!.$ Here, you should
see how this matches the general formula for a Poisson probability,
and evaluate the desired probability. Using software:

```
 dpois(2, 3)
 ## 0.2240418
 exp(-3) * 3^2 / factorial(2)
 ## 0.2240418
```

**Comparison.** You can see that the Binomial and Poisson answers agree to three decimal places.
Your textbook may also have a section that discusses the
circumstances in which Binomial and Poisson distributions
give almost exactly the same results.

Below is a graph of some probabilities from the distribution
$Binom(300, .01),$ represented by bars, and approximating
probabilities from $Pois(3),$ centers of purple circles.

[image]