# Probability for binomial variable to take values below some bound

Tags: probability

This is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733777/probability-of-losing-network-on-any-given-day) and is a homework question.

Binomial random var with $n = 300$, $p = .01$

Question in verbatim is:

> The company is considering replicating their core software system across the network such that the system is operable so long as fewer than $k$ switches fail. If switches fail with probability $1\%$ on any given day, what is the smallest $k$ that ensures that the core system is up $99\%$
>   of days?

So my interpretation is:
Find the smallest $k$ such that the probability of there being less than $k$ successes on any given trial is greater than or equal to $0.99$.

I am a little stuck, I found the expected value to be 3 and the variance to be $2.97$. Then I looked at the markov bound for $P(X \ge k) \le 3/k$ which should represent the probability that $X$ takes a value $\ge k$. Solving this gives me $300$ for the $k$ value which doesn't seem quite right. The intuition was $1 - (\text{Probability that $\ge k$ servers fail}) = (\text{Probability that $< k$ servers fail})$

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the expected value is so small compared to the number of trials, approximating this with a Poisson distribution makes sense.  The expected value is $np = 300\times 0.01 = 3$.  The probability that a Poisson-distributed random variable with expected value $3$ is equal to a particular number $x$ is
$$
\frac{3^x e^{-3}}{x!}.
$$
So you're looking at
$$
\sum_{x=0}^k \frac{3^x e^{-3}}{x!}
$$
and asking what $k$ must be in order to make the sum $\ge 0.99$.
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-3} 3^0}{0!} & = 0.049\ldots \\[10pt]
e^{-3} \left( \frac{3^0}{0!} + \frac{3^1}{1!} \right) & = 0.199\ldots \\[10pt]
e^{-3} \left( \frac{3^0}{0!} + \frac{3^1}{1!} + \frac {3^2}{2!} \right) & = 0.423\ldots \\[10pt]
e^{-3} \left( \frac{3^0}{0!} + \frac{3^1}{1!} + \frac {3^2}{2!} + \frac{3^3}{3!} \right) & = 0.647\ldots \\[10pt]
e^{-3} \left( \frac{3^0}{0!} + \frac{3^1}{1!} + \frac {3^2}{2!} + \frac{3^3}{3!} + \frac{3^4}{4!} \right) & = 0.815\ldots
\end{align}
and so on.  Keep going until you get $\ge0.99$.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer. Could you explain why a poisson distribution is more applicable than a binomial? I have a conflicting answer compared to a friend and I was wondering if the restriction that events may not happen at the same time for poisson might be leading to an underestimate?

Comment: A binomial is a perfect fit, but might be computationally laborious to the point of being intractable. $\qquad$